# Is there olap server or cubes based on PHP?

Tags: open-source, php, server

Is there an OLAP server or cubes written in PHP? For example, Python has [cubes](http://cubes.databrewery.org/index.html). I want to develop simple BI apps (dashboard) fully based on PHP and I need an open source one. At least it support for creating cube (slicing and dicing), because querying directly from database will have bad performance, I think. Thanks

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. What features do you need? What is your price limit if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: Not my area of experience, but for starters [Wikipedia has a comparison list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OLAP_Servers) which also mentions *Cubes.* Unfortunately, they don't mention the programming languages along.

Comment: @Izzy, yeah I have searched on wikipedia, but as you said, they don't mention programming language, and I also browses for all olap mention there. No one built on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Essential PivotGrid for PHP](http://php.syncfusion.com/#BusinessIntelligence/PivotGrid/olap.php) is an option to consider.

[image: PHP OLAP]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider your suggestion